# Flutter create own class

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to create a class with methods inside to a specific Authentication process

So I have created a file MyAuthMethods.dart

```
class UserAuth {

  static int seconds = 10000000;
  static String username;
  static String password;
  static String key = "abc123";

  static Future<String> _generateAuthCode(seconds, username, password, key) async{
    var result = "something";
    print("Seconds: seconds, Username: username, Password: password, Key: key");

    return result;
  }

}
```

on my form (FormScreen.dart), a button has onPressed to execute the function

```
onPressed:(){
  UserAuth._generateAuthCode(UserAuth.seconds, "username", "password", UserAuth.key);
}
```

but it does not work. It says:

```
error: The method '_generateAuthCode' isn't defined for the class 'UserAuth'.
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no keywords like public, protected and private in Dart. In order to make a variable or function private to a class, the name of the variable or function needs to start with underscore(`_`). Variables/function without underscore(`_`) are public. You have defined a private function and accessing the private function. You can fix  by making the function public: in order to do so just remove the underscore from the function, make it `generateAuthCode`.

```
class UserAuth {

  static int seconds = 10000000;
  static String username;
  static String password;
  static String key = "abc123";

  static Future<String> generateAuthCode(seconds, username, password, key) async{
    var result = "something";
    print("Seconds: seconds, Username: username, Password: password, Key: key");

    return result;
  }

}
```

Comment: Go it. Sorry but new to dart. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RaffaeleColleo No problem. I also got stuck on this one too.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Java, Dart doesn’t have the keywords public, protected, and private. If an identifier starts with an underscore (_), it’s private to its library.

[Libraries and visibility](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#libraries-and-visibility)

So _generateAuthCode is the private method for your class , so that only you are not allowed to access.